# How can I create bot joined and send guild info in my support server?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How can I add when someone adds my bot to their server the bot will send a message on my support server the info of that server is joined.
Like an embed:
title: Bot joined a new server
description: guild name, guild id, guild invite link or server invite link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `guildCreate` event of the `Client` class for this. (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate)

The `guildCreate` event returns the `guild` parameter in the callback which is the guild where the bot has been added. Here is a small example how you could use this event:

```js
const client = new Client({intents: ['Your Intents Here']});

client.on('guildCreate', guild => {
    const mainguild = client.guilds.cache.get('Your Guild ID Here');
    const channel = mainguild.channels.cache.get('Your Channel ID Here');

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setColor(`GREEN`)
    .setTitle(`Bot has been added`)
    .setAuthor(guild.name, guild.iconURL({dynamic: true}))
    .setDescription(`I've been added to the server '${guild.name}'. Here you have some more info...`)
    .setTimestamp();

    channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
});
```

You can see [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) which properties and functions you can use for your embed

Comment: error : 
const channel = mainguild.cache.get('916029607436754954');
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/TOD/index.js:313:37)

Comment: Sorry, see I've made a mistake in my example. I've changed it so it should work now.

Comment: Yeah i got the error and i also added guild createInvite